# Importing csv file with line breaks to R or Python Pandas

Tags: python, r, csv

I have a csv file that includes line breaks within columns:

```
"id","comment","x"
1,"ABC\"xyz",123
2,"xyz\"abc",543
3,"abc
xyz",483
```

ID 3, for example contains such a line break.

How can this be imported into python or R? Also, I don't mind if those line breaks were to be replaced by a space, for example.

Comment: have a look at this, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html, you can set delimiters, headers and pretty much everything else you need.  Its just `df=pd.read_csv(path to file)`

Comment: Line breaks won't be a problem, they are correctly handled by R's `read.csv` and pandas' `read_csv`. However, in your file, the double quotes are not properly escaped (it should be "" instead of \"), and this point could be problematic.

Comment: In R, `read.csv` has issues with the escaping, but `readr::read_csv` and `data.table::fread` handle it fine without further parameter adjustment.

Comment: i've tried all the standard options for R like read.csv and also for pandas (read_csv), but none worked. for example, test <- read.csv("test.csv", header = TRUE) results in a warning and the resulting dataframe. it seems the "escaped" upper quote is misleading for those functions. the result is simply a new record after that linebreak for id 3. readr::read_csv() worked without changing any of the default parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python has built-in CSV reader which handles that for you. See [csv documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

```
import csv

with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    csv_rows = list(reader)
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use python pandas library [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function. Make sure to specify escape char.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_csv', sep=',', escapechar='\\')
```

Please note second backslash escaping first one. It has nothing to do with pandas or csv.

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 4):

the problem seemed to be not the line breaks, but rather the escaped upper quotes within the columns: `\"`.

Python: zvone's answer worked fine!

```
import csv

with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    csv_rows = list(reader)
```

R: `readr::read_csv` worked without having to change any of the defaults.

Comment: Great observation on escape character! The best solution is the one that uses `pandas.read_csv(...,escapechar='\\')`